# Why doesn't git branch command show any branches?

Tags: git, git-branch

Few months ago I was going through a tutorial teaching git. There was the main branch (obviously) and then I created a second branch.

Now I'm back at learning git and when I try to see the branches available using
`git branch` I don't get anything. Not even a main branch which is there by default.

What could be the problem?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the output of `git status` say?   Does it say that you are in a branch?

Comment: Are you sure that `git` is the actual git program?  Maybe you made your own command alias named `git` that does something else?  Try typing `which git`

Comment: Do not post pictures of _text._ Everything in that screenshot is _text_. Copy the text and paste it right into your question _as text_ and format it (as code).

Comment: @JohnGordon i did that and then saw your comment. It helped! Thank you

Comment: There are thousands of people with voting privileges, making an assumption there’s “a guy” who does it all seems a bit unwise. Case in point, this post has 2 downvotes. Can’t be that guy.  Remember that voting can be changed, so maybe once you’ve taken the time to improve the question, as you’ve been told very specifically how to do, you’ll see some changes. Or not, because the voters may be long gone by now. Either way, the power to improve it is with you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no context but I’m assuming that you are in a fresh repository.

```
git init
```

Yes, if you then do this you will get no output:

```
git branch
```

Because you are on an “unborn branch”; you haven’t created any commits yet
so there is no branch to point to.

If you however create a commit:

```
touch a.txt
git add a.txt
git commit -mInit
```

Then you will see the branch:

```
$ git branch
* main
```

Because the branch has been born (it points to something).

Comment: Is this wrong? (1 more to go...)

Comment: I did create commits on both branches, however, see none of the branches

Comment: Ah, I had a repository inside of the repostitory. And I worked inside that inner repo. If I go into it and run git branch, I get the branches

Answer (score 0):

You need to make at least one commit for the `git branch` command to list branches. Use the following command to make a commit. And then run `git branch`.

```
git commit -a -m "The Commit message"
```

This will show all the branches, that are remote or local:

```
git branch -av
```

Or if you don't have the branch locally, you can run:

```
git fetch --all
```

And if none of that works, I recommend you to read this documentation on [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-push-anything-to-github-using-git-bash/).